# Stopping a blocking receive without closing the socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am facing a design problem related to sockets and multi-threading.

Let the following things :

- A stack of network protocols whose bottom layer is a socket layer using TCP/IP.
- A "sender" thread that :

  - Performs the connection process (which involves sending and receiving data)
  - Once the connection is established, starts a "receiver" thread that receives data in the background.
  - Sends data.
  - When the application decides to exit, stops the receiver thread.
  - Performs the disconnection (which also involves sending and receiving data).
- A "receiver" threads that receives the data during the data exchange phase, i.e between a connection and a disconnection.

My problem is that, when the sender thread wants to perform the disconnection process, it first needs to stop the receiver thread. Because the receiver thread is performing a blocking receive, the only way to stop it that I am aware of is to brutally close the socket. But doing so would prevent me from performing a clean disconnection because the disconnection process requires to send and receive data before closing the socket.

So my question is : is it possible to stop a blocking receive without closing the socket and if yes, how can I do it ? Or do I need to redesign my application ?

I could add a timeout to my blocking receive in order to periodically check whether to stop receiving, but it would feel not very responsive and seems to be a dirty approach.

I'm not bothering you with the full code because it works as intended and has dependencies. My receive is performed with a select() and then a recv() as follows :

```
iRes = select( 0, & fdRead, NULL, NULL, m_nTmout == 0 ? NULL : & tv );
...
iRes = recv( m_hSock, (char *) pBytes, nMaxLen, 0 );
```

This is Win32 code, but I also have something similar on Linux (Android to be more specific). In both case I'm using C and C++.

Thank you.

Comment: putting a timeout on the receiving thread's reads would only affect responsiveness at the point of exit - it should have negligible effect during normal running (albeit at a small cost of CPU used since the thread won't be completely blocked when it's not reading)

Comment: True, but there has to be a cleaner way, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is, actually, at least not portably.    The only way I know is to send a signal to each child thread so that the read in progress gets killed with an EINTR error code (on POSIX systems)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Unfortunately I'm not targetting only POSIX systems so I should maybe use the timeout approach.

Comment: If disconnection process involves sending and receiving data(at application layer), can receiving thread not identify(by looking at received data) disconnection is initiated and it need to stop

Comment: By "blocking receive" you mean "blocking `select()` call", but not `recv()` call, don't you? As you have `select()` which informs that something appears in the socket, you don't need the socket itself to be opened in blocking mode.

Comment: @Pras What you are suggesting is that i'm initiating the disconnection process from the sender thread by just sending a first message and waiting until the receiver thread receives the response and stops itself, letting the sender thread resume ?

Comment: Yes kind of signing off the dialog..

Comment: Ok thanks, I will think about this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As you use `select()` for as blocking operation, you may create `pipe()` for passing commands from the *sender* to the *receiver*.

By adding read end of that pipe to the `select()` read list, you may be sure that any command written to that pipe will awoke the `select()` call. So receiver will be able to process this command.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will study that and see if that can be done on all the platforms i'm targetting.